# Grub2 detects Windows 8 instead of 7

Tags: grub2, mbr

I earlier had Windows 7 installed on my laptop...then installed Windows 8 with dual boot setup on a different partition.

Then I didnt like windows 8 so much and decided it to replace with ubuntu 12.04.
So I booted into Live CD and formatted my Windows 8 partition to ext4. Set mountpoint as /. and installed Ubuntu succesfully.

Then when I booted the computer. It detects the Windows 8 system and not Windows 7 which is actually present on my lappy.

When i click on Windows 8 entry in Grub2. It takes me to Windows 8 repairing stuff.
How can i get my system to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu?

Comment: Already tried sudo update-grub?

Comment: @Nando, this will not help because problem is whithin Windows, not GRUB.

Comment: @Danatela it probably will fix it if grub is pointing to the wrong partition (the repair partition and not the OS).

Comment: I think it's detecting Windows's recovery partition that the installer didn't delete.

Comment: Yes..first thing I did was update-grub. Would still loader the windowa 8 bootloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not Grub2 problem. It is related to BCD configuration. Actually, Windows 8 replaces every bootloader without confirmation like any Windows does. And Microsoft apparently had chosen wrong way last time, because their so called "boot screen" is not actually *boot screen* but *logon screen*. When you deleted Windows 8 partition, you made Windows system totally unbootable. Now you should perform these steps to correct the problem:

1. Choose Windows 8 in GRUB2 menu.
2. Find entry "Run earlier version of Windows" and select it. (May be you need to hold F8, not sure).
3. Reboot.
4. Repeat step 1.
5. Boot into Windows 7.
6. Run [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). There, you should do:

   - Rewrite Windows bootloader.
   - Set up Windows 7 boot entry and set it to default.
7. Reboot into Ubuntu and update GRUB menu.
8. Check if Windows 7 starts normally.

And you always can restore Windows 7 bootloader using it's installation media, then [restore GRUB again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/88432#88432).

Comment: Hi ...thanks for your solution ^_^  worked like charm. Also chose windows 7 as default os througjt msconfig otherwise it would everytime show windows 8 and 7 in dual boot menu. The only problem now is that the "system reserved" partition is still of win 8 and in grub to it shows windows 8 loader instead of 7 thought boots into 7. Nonetheless it does the purpose. P.s must say ubuntu users get fast support

Comment: Well, if my answer solves your problem, there is a little thing you can do for me in return: accept it. This will help me (and not only me) provide more operative help.

Comment: yah,sorry i had tried that before too. but was pressing the wrong button :P done now.